# C++ OpenGL ES 2.0 Matrix Transforms - Newbie

Tags: c++, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to work out OpenGL ES 2.0 and I am pretty much an OpenGL newbie. I have a simple program that at the moment just draws a red square at the origin and I want to use a matrix to move it from the origin to the centre of the screen. I believe I have done everything correctly so far but I must be missing something as when I apply the matrix to the shader I just get a blank screen.

Shader:

```
const char vShaderStr[] = "attribute vec4 a_position; \n"
        "attribute vec4 a_colour; \n"
        "varying vec4 v_colour; \n"
        "uniform mat4 u_transformation; \n"
        "void main() \n"
        "{ \n"
        "       v_colour = a_colour; \n"
        "       gl_Position = u_transformation * a_position; \n"
        "} \n";
const char fShaderStr[] = "varying vec4 v_colour; \n"
        "void main() \n"
        "{ \n"
        "       gl_FragColor = v_colour; \n"
        "} \n";
```

Create matrix and send to shader:

```
transformationMatrix = glGetUniformLocation(programObject, "u_transformation");
...
GLfloat vMatrix[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    };
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformationMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, vMatrix);
```

Do I have to do some maths with this matrix before it is sent to the shader? If so how? I feel I am missing something glaringly obvious to most people here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix is probably wrong. Assuming everything else is set up correctly, this would be the correct matrix:

```
GLfloat vMatrix[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks! So you have to start with the identity matrix first and then change the other values around it.

Comment: Yup, otherwise u_transformation * a_position will yield an incorrect value (x=0,y=0,z=0).